# Ubuntu 20.10 and NGINX debug

Tags: server, nginx, 20.10

I found something that said that the version of nginx that comes with Ubuntu (and this was old) already had debugging enabled, but I'm on Ubuntu 20.10 and can't seem to figure out how to turn it on. I tried stopping nginx and starting nginx.debug but that didn't work. I also did `sudo apt search nginx` and looked for debug and found nothing.

Am I going to have to build this from scratch or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Default configuration file of Nginx in 20.10 is in the same location as older version:

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

There you can find the logging settings (default):

```
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
```

Look in those folders for the "debugging" - i.e. /var/log/nginx/...

NGinx docs show you how to add debug:
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/monitoring/debugging/